# TestFlight: iOS project builds for different environments

Tags: ios, iphone, continuous-integration, testflight

How to use TestFlight with iOS project builds for different environments?
I can use wildcard Provisioning Profile but can't have different App Id for different environments(my environments using different App ID). Maybe it's OK to use few iTunes Connect apps, one app for one environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I distinguish between STAGE and PRODUCTION builds on iTunes Connect / Apple TestFlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839630/how-can-i-distinguish-between-stage-and-production-builds-on-itunes-connect-ap)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create as many apps as you like in iTunes Connect. So create on app per bundle identifier and upload your builds. Once ready to submit just use the app with the production bundle id and environment and submit your app for the app store there.